# Is there a method_missing in scala?

Tags: scala, method-missing

similar to the one in Ruby

Comment: This question doesn't even make sense. If you have a practical problem, you should ask how to solve it instead of asking how to implement what you think is the solution.

Comment: There is a `method_missing` equivalent in Scala 2.9, see my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is no longer strictly true with the `Dynamic` trait found in [experimental] Scala 2.9. See the answer from Kipton Barros, for example.

However, `Dynamic` is still *not quite* like `method_missing`, but rather employs compiler magic to effectively rewrite method calls to "missing" methods, as determined statically, to a proxy (`applyDynamic`). It is the approach of statically-determining the "missing" methods that differentiates it from `method_missing` from a polymorphism viewpoint: one would need to try and *dynamically forward* (e.g. with reflection) methods to get true `method_missing` behavior. (Of course this can be avoided by avoiding sub-types :-)

---

**No. Such a concept does not exist in Java or Scala.**

Like Java, all the methods in Scala are 'bound' at compile time (this also determines what method is used for overloading, etc). If a program does compile, said method exists (or did according to the compiler), otherwise it does not. This is why you can get the [NoSuchMethodError](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) if you change a class definition without rebuilding all affected classes.

If you are just worried about trying to call a method on an object which conforms to a signature ("typed duck typing"), then perhaps you may be able to get away with [structural typing](http://codemonkeyism.com/scala-goodness-structural-typing/). Structural typing in Scala is magical access over reflection -- thus it defers the 'binding' until runtime and a runtime error may be generated. Unlike method_missing this does not allow the *target* to handle the error, but it does allow the caller to (and the caller could theoretically call a defined methodMissing method on the target... but this is probably not the best way to approach Scala. Scala is not Ruby :-)

Comment: While structural type is implemented using reflection, it is checked statically at compile time just like a class.

Comment: Of course, this is no longer true - this answer should be unaccepted

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Thanks for pointing out that it is no longer [entirely] true and making me update my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 12):

**Yes**, as of Scala 2.9 with the `-Xexperimental` option, one can use the `Dynamic` trait
([scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/Dynamic.html)). Classes that extend `Dynamic` get the magical method `applyDynamic(methodName, args)` which behaves like Ruby's `method_missing`.

Among other things, the `Dynamic` trait can be useful for interfacing with dynamic languages on the JVM.

Answer (score 6):

Not really. It doesn't make sense. Scala is a statically-typed language in which methods are bound at compile time; Ruby is a dynamically-typed language in which *messages* are passed to objects, and these messages are evaluated at runtime, which allows Ruby to handle messages that it doesn't directly respond to, à la `method_missing`.

You can mimic `method_missing` in a few ways in Scala, notably by using the Actors library, but it's not quite the same (or nearly as easy) as Ruby's `method_missing`.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible in Scala 2.8 and earlier.

Comment: It is actually possible with recent versions of Scala